# Create a picking list or send with an e-mail

Tags: magento-1.7, template, email-templates

I need to add a feature to my website that creates picking list for warehouse.

When you go to sales>orders>view an order>shipments>click on a shipment> You will see a print button which prints picking slip. I want to add a button called e-mail. When you click on the button it should send the picking list to an e-mail I set. Also I need to change the picking slip template.

For also learning purpose could you help me please? So where should I start? Where can I change the template and how can I add the e-mail button?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be one for a module - http://www.moogento.com/magento-pickpack-picklist.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build this yourself you would have to start out with building your own extension. There are a couple of nice tutorials on that [here](http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/) and [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) but it comes down to having an extension with a `config.xml`, perhaps a `Data helper` and `Models`.

The config.xml would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
            </[module]>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Helper</class>
            </[module]>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now moving on to actually kicking into action when a shipment is created. For this Magento offers `Events`. A nice tutorial on events can be found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method). We just need to find the right event that triggers when the Shipment is created. We can use the [Magento 1.7 event cheatsheet](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/) for that. `sales_order_shipment_save_after` should do the trick for you.
Lets start by adding your observer to the config.xml INSIDE the `global` tag.

```
<events>
    <sales_order_shipment_save_after>
        <observers>
            <[module]_shipping_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>sendList</method>
            </[module]_shipping_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_shipment_save_after>     
</events>
```

This tells Magento to fire class `[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer`, method `sendList` when the event is triggered.

Now we can add the final piece, the Observer Model. Create a file in the `Model` directory called `Observer.php` and insert the following code.

```
<?php 

class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract 
{

    public function sendList($observer)
    {
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();

        [...] 
        retrieve items and send email
        [...]
    }

}
```

Now you have your basic observer. You will need to add code to retrieve the items of a shipment, probably something along the lines of `$products = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->setOrderFilter($orderid);` and I suggest using [this tutorial](http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/) or [this tutoral](http://www.techflirt.com/magento-send-custom-email/) on how to send the email.

Comment: No problem, let me know how it went :)